# Can you use environmental variables in qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, qt-creator, qmake

So I use a bunch of libraries in the code I'm currently working in.  Right now I include them by doing things like `win32:LIBS += "C:/my/location/Tools/libcurl/trunk/lib/Debug/curllib.lib"`.  However, I have an environmental variable that defined `%TOOLS%` as `C:/my/location/Tools/`.  I tried to simply change my include to `win32:LIBS += "%TOOLS%libcurl/trunk/lib/Debug/curllib.lib"`, but it could not find the files.  I looked online and this should be doable.  Am I missing something simple, like a way to tell Qt creator to look at window's environmental variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the content of an environment variable when qmake is processed, you can use the following :

```
win32:LIBS += $$(TOOLS)/libcurl/trunk/lib/Debug/curllib.lib
```

`TOOLS` should be an environment variable set to `C:/my/location/Tools`.

But you don't necessarily need an environment variable for this. You can simple define a variable in your .pro file :

```
TOOLS="C:/my/location/Tools"
```

And use it's value by prefixing it with `$$` :

```
win32:LIBS += $$TOOLS/libcurl/trunk/lib/Debug/curllib.lib
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  I guess I missed the `$$()` vs `%()%` difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$$VAR => QMake variable's value at the time qmake is run
$${VAR} => QMake variable's value at time qmake is run (subtle difference)
$(VAR) => Contents of an Environment variable at the time Makefile (not qmake) is run
```

In your Case:
**$$(TOOLS) return the Path you need.**